# Wrong Country Code Transmitted in CLIP when calling internationally

Tags: gsm, telecommunication

I do realise this question sounds off-topic for SO - it's probably more on-topic for Travel.SE but it is also really a debugging question and requires a bit of a hacker mindset to debug, so I figured SO is the place to go.

Here's the problem: When I make an international call from my phone on H2OWireless (a reseller using the AT&T GSM network), the receiving end of my call gets a wrong country code transmitted as caller ID, causing a number of problems.

I have a US phone number with area code 803. If I make a call to Germany, the receiver of the call sees my caller ID as 00803xxxx, which does not make sense. My caller ID should be shown as +1803xxx or 001803xxx, but for some reason, the leading "1" gets lost.

That causes the following problem: I can call regular dumb landline phones in Germany, but when I try to call my bank, my call bounces at their switchboard. I guess they are doing some kind of a reverse-lookup and find that +8 or +83 is not a valid country code, and refuse to accept that call.

I have temporarily solved the problem by having a friend setup a call forwarding for me, so he forwards my call to my bank when I call him.
But I would really like to understand what is going wrong here, and whether AT&T or Deutsche Telekom or any other provider is to blame for this problem.

I would appreciate any insight from phone network experts as to how to debug the problem, so that I can see who is causing this before I write a mail to either AT&T support or the german provider.

Comment: Have you tried (a) with your SIM in a phone from a different manufacturer, and (b) a SIM from a different provider in your phone?  Would narrow down if the information is coming from the phone or the SIM.  If one of these combinations works, then as a quick solution, I would probably just change whichever one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the reseller not mapping the calling number correctly - I would write the letter to them. It will be much easier for them to debug it than for you, especially if they are actually obliged to do it correctly by law/licence (I am not sure what the rules are in the US). If it is a problem with someone else they will normally be delighted to let you know (!) and you can then chase the guilty party instead.

The reason this most commonly happens is because the reseller generally jumps off the regular network to their own IP network and they have to translate the call setup info to match the protocol they are using on their own network (probably SIP based unless it is quite old). It is not uncommon for CLI data to get mixed up this way.